# Passing Model to the partial view doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The file "*Add.cshtml*" is calling the partial view "*_ManagePartial.cshtml*" and passing the "*Model*""however the "*Model* " is not being picked up in the partial view.

When I include the code that's on the partial view into "*Add.cshtml*" everything works great.

Please advise what I''m doing wrong.

**Error Message:**
[Click here to see the error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Srkh7.png)

***File***: _ManagePartial.cshtml

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-lg" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserPassword)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-lg" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserEmail)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-lg" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserConfirmPassword)
            <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" name="UserConfirmPassword">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***File***: Add.cshtml

```
@model CardDistro.Models.AddUserViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Current = "Users@Index";
    String Action = ViewBag.FormAction;
}

<h2 class="page-header">@ViewBag.Title</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm(Action, "Users", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SiteAddUserContainer" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="UserID" value="@Model.UserID" />
    if (ViewBag.Retval != null){
        <div class="row"><div class="col-md-8"><div class="alert alert-danger">@ViewBag.Retval</div></div></div>
    }
    Html.RenderPartial("_ManagePartial", Model);
}
```

Comment: Did you declare a `@model` for _ManagePartial.cshtml?

Comment: @Jasen thanks it works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_ManagePartial.cshtml` needs to identify the model by starting the partial view with

`@model CardDistro.Models.AddUserViewModel`

so the compiler knows what to do with `model=>UserName`